# Atomically push settings to azure app config

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-app-configuration

I'm using an azure devops pipeline to push a json config file to azure app config. According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/push-kv-devops-pipeline#parameters) there's a setting that can be enabled:

> Delete all other Key-Values in store with the specified prefix and label: Default value is Unchecked.
> Checked: Removes all key-values in the App Configuration store that match both the specified prefix and label before pushing new key-values from the configuration file.
> Unchecked: Pushes all key-values from the configuration file into the App Configuration store and leaves everything else in the App Configuration store intact.

When the setting is enabled, it sounds as if the operation performs two steps: a delete and then an update. I don't want that the application checks for config to find it missing.

**Is it possible to update all the config at once atomically, like a http put?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the App Configuration service perspective, each key-value is always updated (and deleted or created) individually via separate requests, so there is no atomic operation when changes of multiple key-values are involved. Applications should be designed to be tolerable of the transitioning states. Alternatively, you can consider using other mechanisms to notify applications what is good timing to pick up/refresh configuration.

Comment: 1. Maybe it's a very unlikely scenario, but the values could be deleted and then an app could start up and see nothing in the config. Is it right to be worried about this? 

2. Let's say I have a particular key, whose value must be set in order to indicate that _all_ the values are set. Is it possible to then do a simple check for this value, and if it exists to enable fetching the rest of the values?

Comment: In answer to my own questions - I think I can do the following:
1. Create a key with a unique label, e.g. "RefreshSentinel"
2. Configure refresh to watch this key and update _all_ keys on change
3. Push the config associated a different label, e.g. "AppSettings". This will delete the existing "AppSettings", but leave the sentinel untouched
4. Push the sentinel config value